# Why Visual Studio 2010 reset window layout is different from what I had

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I used to have pending changes, error list, find and replace and several other windows at the bottom when I reset window layout. But after a VS crash and restore, now when I reset window layout I don't have those windows anymore. How can I resume the previous default window layout setting?

Comment: Window + Windows + Save.

Comment: Thanks Hans, but it doesn't work. Save is to save the unsaved documents.

Comment: Hmm, no, that would be File + Save.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press `View` in main menu and turn on windows you are interested in.
Some windows, like search results will only appear as result of corresponding action.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to configure windows. But how do I save the window layout so next time when I reset I still get them?

Comment: It will be saved when you close visual studio gracefully (make sure there is just one instance running or last closed vs will override it's layour) or in main menu Window -> Windows -> Save.